# Multiple Checkbox Form Issue using Ajax and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to make a form that is in a loop has a unique id.
The issue with this is only the first form is working and all the rest after is not triggering the jquery code.

Form:

```
<?php foreach( $tasks as $tasks ) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $tasks->title ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $newDate; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tasks->details ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $tasks->category ?></td>
    <td>

<form class="noclass">
    <input class="hideit id" type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $tasks->id ?>" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $tasks->user ?>" name="value" id="checkbox-2-1" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" <?php echo $tasks->user ?> />
</form>

</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#checkbox-2-1').click(function() {
            var id = $(".id").val();
            var value = $(".check").val();
            var dataString = '?id=' + id + '&value=' + value + '&user=<?php echo $id ?>';
            alert(dataString);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://example.com/process.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
            });
        })
    })
    return false;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
var id = $(".id").val();  
var value = $(".check").val();
```

and what `$(".id")` and `$(".check")' will return is object.

So you need to convert it into string of key value pair and then send it.

Also refer Gautam answer for `foreach` correction.

**ONE MORE**

**You are repeating `checkbox-2-1` id for checkbox evert-time loop gets execute and ID for each dom must be unique.**

**What i suggest**

Use code as below.

for checkbox click event use

`$('input:ckeckbox[name="value"]').on('change',function(){  });`

and inside `function(){ }` write code for getting value of `class` `id` and `check` as below

```
$(this).closest('form.noclass').find('.id').val();
$(this).closest('form.noclass').find('.value').val()
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie, How can I alert what these values hold?

Comment: just create `variable` that hold value and then `alert` it as normal.. `var id = $(this).closest('form.noclass').find('.id').val(); alert(id);`

Answer (score 1):

Your first form is not closing....close like this

```
<form class="noclass">
    <input class="hideit id" type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $tasks->id ?>" />
</form>
<form class="noclass">
    <input class="hideit id" type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $tasks->id ?>" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $tasks->user ?>" name="value" id="checkbox-2-1" class="regular-checkbox big-checkbox" <?php echo $tasks->user ?> />
</form>
```

And what is

```
<?php foreach( $tasks as $tasks ) : ?>
```

try to give another variable like

```
<?php foreach( $tasks as $task ) : ?>
```

and then change the symultanious